# Executing a Java class file using the command line, but from the "wrong" directory

Tags: java, command-line-interface

`App.java` is a simple "Hello World" app in directory `/home/abcd` and is part of package `abcd`; that is, it has a header `package abcd;`. I can easily compile and run the app, from the `/home` directory with `javac abcd/App.java` and run it from the upper (i.e. `/home`) directory with `java abcd.App`.

How can I run the class file from the "wrong" directory, e.g., from sub-directory `abcd` itself, or indeed from any other directory.

Despite having turned up several stackoverflow questions with titles that suggest they address this problem, none that I've found quite does so.

Comment: The package is part of the class name. So you **can't** run the class from the "wrong" directory (although you can specify a classpath). Or you can build a jar file (a zip with a tiny bit of metadata) containing the directory structure necessary for the class to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `/home` as the class path (or rather, add it to the class path). It's the directory under which your package structure is located.

From anywhere, you can run

```
java -cp /home/ abcd.App
```

You can also use a relative path for the class path, which means this should work from within `/home/abcd/`:

```
java -cp .. abcd.App
```

Comment: Thank you. Hours of frustration put to rest. More importantly for me is that fact that your answer is *more* than I asked and deepens my understanding as well as solving my problem.